# Best practices for ordering columns in SQL when creating the table

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I have a table foo which contains the following columns

```
create table foo (
id integer not null auto_increment unique,
name varchar(255),
desc varchar(255),
modified_time datetime not null,
type tinyint(1)
)
```

Are there any best practices in following a ordering convention for all the columns (e.g. in a alphabetical fashion or not nulls at the top and rest of the columns at the bottom)

Comment: `desc` is a keyword, and left unquoted like that it can (and probably will) cause problems. Either use `description`, or quote the name with backticks. I always quote with backticks regardless of keywords or not, so I don't have to care :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly the primary key **first**.
The name of that column is usually *tablename*_id (traditional) or just 'id' (preferred by frameworks such as rails).

If used, usually a **name/description field** next, as you have it.

I tend to put **foreign keys** after that (parents first, children after that) as they tend to be more critical during development.

Then I group **other data**, e.g. address line, city, state, zip together.

When no other rule fits, I tend to prefer **required** fields higher up for increased visibility.

**timestamps** (some/all of created_on, updated_on, removed_on, etc.) usually **last**

So in your example I would actually do:

```
create table foo (
id integer not null auto_increment unique,
name varchar(255),
type tinyint(1),
desc varchar(255),
modified_time datetime not null
)
```

Note - As Kolink noted, use description over desc because desc is a reserved word meaning descending, e.g. `order desc`

> However... big disclaimer...

if your table changes over time (i.e. real world) and you have existing production data, you will not have the fields ordered as initially 'planned'.  This can be avoided by export and re-import but in many cases its best to accept that ordering is just a convention for initial creation for programmer convenience and that alone.

Another popular topic here is column name naming conventions.  That's a whole 'nother topic but I'll tip my toe in by saying don't abbreviate unless forced!

Comment: Never really thought about this topic before, but this is a good list of heuristics that I tend to subconsciously follow now that I do think about it haha

Answer (score 2):

Not only is there no real convention, but it's best not to think about one.  Sometimes insert queries, for example, will not specify field names when it's assumed that you're going to update every field.  But then you have to specify values in an assumed order.  This is error-prone.  So the best way to think about it is, "these columns are present in this table, in no particular order."

Comment: +1 I agree "best not to think about one". Particularly when adding columns to an existing table no point about getting hung up on it being in the "right" place. In SQL Server that would require rebuilding the whole table. Not sure if MySQL is the same.

Answer (score 0):

No not really.  It's flexible so that order your columns however you wish.

I suppose the main convention is to ensure that you have your `primary_key` as the first column in your table.

Comment: And sort by it descending if it needs to show latest rows first.

Answer (score 0):

I have personaly never heard or seen such conventions. The only conventions used for database columns are usually naming convention (which is often different from one organisation to another) and data type mapping.

However conventions are simply what they are. So if it feels right to you to sort your columns alphabetically do so.

Answer (score 0):

It does not really matter and is a question of taste, I'd say.

You want to make sure that you are using the same order of columns in your indexes as you use in frequent queries, but that's all.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is not. I personally prefer putting the primary (often surrogate) key, which I think every table should have, in front, followed by a name/description (username for users, productname for products), if there is any relevant, unique descriptive name field. Then a foreign key to a logical parent (orderid for orderlines) if there is any. After that, I order them in whichever way suits me best, often grouping related fields (lastEditDate and lastEditedBy next to each other). I see no good reason for alphabetically ordering columns.